# Вода из крана или вода из-под крана?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, словосочетания

Как правильно: *вода **из** крана* или *вода **из-под** крана*?

Спорим тут...

Answer (score 4):

Течёт вода чаще всего "**из крана**" (исключая некоторые случаи описания процессов с участием вытекающей воды).

Вода такого *происхождения* может быть названа обоими способами: **вода "из крана"** или **"из-под" крана**. Последнее добавляет уточнение, что такую воду обычно получают наполнением подставленной **под кран** ёмкости. Это устойчивое обозначение водопроводной воды, которую пьют без обработки (не кипятят или не фильтруют).

*Пить воду* (действие) физически возможно и непосредственно **из крана** (напр. через трубку) или **из-под крана** (подобравшись к струе). Выражение "я пил воду из крана" вне контекста означает, скорее, способ её употребления, чем происхождение.

Таким образом, выбирая выражение, нужно учитывать смысл, который требуется передать.